# Key Events through a service

Tags: android, service, keyevent

I have a service that plays a notification sound. The sound is user defined so it can be anything. If it has a long play time I want the user to be able to stop it by pressing any physical button on the phone. How do I go about setting up my OnKeyListener?

Comment: private OnKeyListener mKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   RingtoneManager rm = new RingtoneManager(AlarmService.this);
   rm.stopPreviousRingtone();
   return false;
  }
  
 }; i dont who to set the listener to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in general.

If the device has a CAMERA or MEDIA button (latter being on wired headsets), and if the foreground activity does not consume the event, then there is a broadcast `Intent` (`ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON` and `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`, respectively) that you can listen for. However, relatively few devices will have one of these.